# Is there a way to add data to an already existing row in a csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv

```
with open('file.csv', mode='a') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['Name', 'type', 'website_name', 'url']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(sample_dict)
```

I am currently using just the csv library. This is the code I am using currently but what my current dictionary does is only holds entities related to type and name. I have to run my program through a separate for loop to get multiple websites. However, when I try running the loop with the current function, it starts the websites at the next line. This is what I want the function to do:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzvlw.png)

Comment: what have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried adding the data into the same dictionary but that is not working as it is part of a different loop. I want it to look like the image attached in the post

Comment: What do you mean with "it's part of a different loop"? You need to update the dictionary, there is no way around it. If you gather data somewhere else, pass in the dictionary you already have.